# Writing a wrapper function for multiple value equality overloads

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement value equality for my types, but I've realised I can do this on the interface level, by implementing the following functions for all my interfaces I want equality on.

```
class EqHelper 
{
    public static bool Eq(I1 x, I1 y) { ... }
    public static bool Eq(I2 x, I2 y) { ... }
    public static bool Eq(I3 x, I3 y) { ... }
}
```

`I1`, `I2`, `I3` etc are interfaces, not classes. I've implemented value equality on the interfaces because then I can just call the static `EqHelper.Eq` method from any implementing class and get value equality.

But what I've realised is that the above functions don't check for `null`.

So I tried the following:

```
class EqHelper
{
    public static bool Eq<T>(T x, T y) 
    { 
        if (x != null && y != null) 
        {
            return EqWorker(x,y);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return (x == null) == (y == null);
        }
    }

    public static bool EqWorker(I1 x, I1 y) { ... }
    public static bool EqWorker(I2 x, I2 y) { ... }
    public static bool EqWorker(I3 x, I3 y) { ... }
}
```

But unfortunately this `Eq` now doesn't compile, because of course `EqWorker` doesn't work for all `T`, only the particular overrides.

Is there anyway to do this wrapper nicely? I'd rather not put the null logic in every equality function for each type, that seems even more repetitive than this already is.

On a related note, defining value equality seems like quite a bit of a chore as discussed [in this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type). Is there a nicer way to do it than suggested in the article?

Note that I'm unfortunately stuck on `C#5` and `.NET 2.0` due to the project I'm on. I might be able to sneak up to `C#6` if really required but I'd prefer not to and I definitely can't go past `.NET 2.0` due to WinXP requirements.

I've only been coding `C#` for a few weeks so please tell me if I'm doing something completely silly.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this setup?

Comment: Since you're new to C# I will give you some good advice.  Dont format your code like that.  Use a new line for your braces.  99% of C# programmers write their code with new lined braces and it makes it much easier to read and debug.  Dont believe me?  Well take a look at your `Eq` method, it wont even compile...

Comment: Value equality, primarily for checking against test cases but perhaps for other purposes.

Comment: @maccettura I do I just formatted it differently for stack overflow. I run resharper usually and it spaces quite nicely. But people are on mobile here.

Comment: @Clinton fair enough, but I would still suggest formatting correctly on here as well.  Mobile users can scroll, it won't kill them.  Its hard for me to read your code, plus you've got an error in it.

Comment: More than one error, `T` != `T1` != `T2`. Anyway your `T` is unrestricted, while `I1`, `I2` and `I3` are too specialized, so there is no `EqWorker()` for every `T` as you already correctly observe, making this code fail to compile. What exactly is your question? What have you tried? What are you options? Can you let all interfaces inherit from a base interface, such as `IComparable`? But wait... that one already exists, so why don't they?

Comment: just as a side note: you should really rewrite `return (x == null) == (y == null);` with `return (x == null) && (y == null);`

Comment: I'm not sure i got your problem. But do you know about "where" restrictions, may be it can help?

Comment: @CodeCaster I’m write the null logic only once, as its the same for all types, so it should only need to be written once.